# rotating schedule of 2 items between 5 people

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, scheduling

I do medical coding and there are 5 of us that code for a large practice. 2 of those doctors are the only ones that do certain procedures/surgeries so we want to rotate who does their charges so we all have a chance to code those particular types of procedures. We would rotate monthly with each month, 3 of us would be sitting out without coding for either of those 2 doctors. How would I set this up in Excel? I am "fairly" proficient in Excel but I can't seem to come up with how to do this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick mockup of a table that may get you going.

Column A is the month. Column B and Column C are the coders assigned to the particular doctor.

I've just incremented the coders by month. After 5 months repeat (you can use a simple formula to do the repeating, e.g., in cell b7 the formula would be +b2 etc.)

You can manipulate the first coder in column C depending if you want to have coders to be doing for 2 consecutive months on and 3 consecutive months off. Also, you may need to take into consideration how vacation/sick time is handled.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! So easy but i just couldn't get it started. This is perfect!

Comment: Glad it's what you want. Maybe to handle vacation/sick: have an additional column D titled "backup". Then start that one with coder 5, and increment the same.